# Appending Strings Together In A Card Game

Tags: java, string, object, concatenation

I'm in the process of writing a simple blackjack game and am having a problem with appending the String representation of a dealt card to a String variable DealtCards and then printing it so I can see the list.

It has to be like this: `Ace-Of-Spades`  `Two-Of-Queen`

Every time I run my testDeck App it keeps displaying the new card without displaying both the last one dealt and the new one. It's not adding it to the String

We have not learned arrays yet so **I can't use arrays to do this**

Here is my Deck Class:

```
public class Deck 
{
    private Random random;
    private String dealtCards;

    /**The no-arg constructor simply creates 
    * a new Random object 
    */
    public Deck()
    {
        random = new Random();
        dealtCards = "";
    }
    /** This method will generate random numbers for 
      * the suit and faceValue variables 
      * in order to create a card 
      * @param takes no parameter 
      * @return randomResult represents a new card object 
      * generated by random
      */
    public Card deal()
    {
        int suit = 0, faceValue = 0;

        suit = random.nextInt(3+1);
        faceValue = random.nextInt(13) + 1;

        Card randomResult = new Card(suit, faceValue);
        dealtCards += randomResult.toString(); 

        return randomResult;

    }
    public String cardsDealtList()
    {
        return dealtCards;
    }
}
```

My Card Class:

```
public class Card
{
      private int suit;
      private int faceValue;

    /**The two parameter Constructor initializes
     *the cards suit and facevalue
     *@param suit  represents the card's suit 
     *@param faceValue  represents the card's face value
     */ 
    public Card(int suit, int faceValue)
    {
        if(!(suit >= 0 && suit <= 3))
        {
            suit = 3;
            faceValue = 2;
        }

        this.suit = suit;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;

    }

    /**
     *Returns the suit of the card object 
     *
     *@return the suit of the card object 
     */
    public int getSuit()
    {   
        return suit; 
    }
    /**
     *Returns the faceValue of the card object 
     *
     *@return the faceValue of the card object 
     */
    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return faceValue;
    }

    /**Compare's the current instance to the parameter card 
     *if they are identical, if one is lower than the other 
     *or if one if higher than the other
     *@param card  represents a card object's reference that will 
     *be passed into it during a compareTo method call
     *@return 0 if two cards are identical, 1 if the first card is higher,
     * -1 if the first card is lower 
     */
    public int compareTo(Card card)
    {   

        if(this.getSuit() == card.getSuit() && this.getFaceValue() == card.getFaceValue())

            return 0;

        else if(this.getSuit() < card.getSuit())

            return 1;

        else if(this.getSuit() == card.getSuit() && this.getFaceValue() > card.getFaceValue()) 

            return 1;

        else 

            return -1;
    }

    /** Will return a String representation of the card 
      *
      *@return cardName represents the full name of the card 
      */
    public String toString()
    {
        String cardName = null;

        switch (faceValue)
        {
            case 1: 
            cardName = "Ace";
            break; 

            case 2:
            cardName = "Two";
            break;

            case 3:
            cardName = "Three";
            break; 

            case 4:
            cardName = "Four";
            break;

            case 5:
            cardName = "Five";
            break;

            case 6:
            cardName = "Six";
            break;

            case 7:
            cardName = "Seven";
            break;

            case 8:
            cardName = "Eight";
            break;

            case 9:
            cardName = "Nine";
            break; 

            case 10: 
            cardName = "Ten";
            break;

            case 11: 
            cardName = "Jack";
            break;

            case 12:
            cardName = "Queen";
            break; 

            case 13: 
            cardName = "King";
            break; 


        }
        switch (suit)
        { 

            case 0:
            cardName += "-Of-Spades";
            break; 

            case 1: 
            cardName += "-Of-Hearts";
            break; 

            case 2:
            cardName += "-Of-Diamonds";
            break;

            case 3:
            cardName += "-Of-Clubs";
            break; 

        }

        return cardName;
    }
}
```

And here is my Application Class To Test The Deck Class:

```
public class TestDeck
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Deck deck1 = new Deck();

        Card firstCard = deck1.deal();
        //System.out.println(firstCard);
        System.out.println(deck1.cardsDealtList());
        //how to get the list of dealt card???

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and iterating through your code?

Comment: im a first year student we haven't yet learned how to debug

Comment: You're only dealing one card.

Comment: @user220177 I was never taught how to debug at all. It's something you learn out of your own will.

Comment: but if its a deck of 54 cards shouldn't all the cards dealt be added to the list?

Comment: Your solution is missing... quite a bit.  You'll need to try harder.  I'd start by  having your deck maintain an array of Card... 52 of them.  I'd also make a "Dealer" Class, and a "Hand" class to interact with.  Google Shuffle algorithm to shuffle them.  You've got a long ways to go.

Comment: Yes, all cards dealt should be added to the list, but you're dealing only one card, so you only see one card dealt. It's all about logic.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question this is a Simple card game and I have specific instructions if there are classes that i haven't posted its because they're not in the instructions

Comment: i could do firstCard.toString() but then i wouldn't be able to call the cardsDealtList() method on it because firstCard is Card object and cardsDealtList() is Deck Class method

Comment: You seem a bit confused. Your `cardsDealtList` lists all cards that are already dealt. The only way to deal more than one card is by calling the `deal` method several times.

Comment: If you can display a single card, then next you need to find the collection of cards to display. Where is your collection?

Comment: His "collection" is are the names concatenated into `cardsDealtList`

Comment: @MaxZoom they haven't learnt arrays yet, I doubt he knows how to use `Set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine but you only deal one card.
To have more cards, you need to deal multiple times

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    int cards = 5;  // pull 5 cards
    for (int i=0 ; i < cards; i++ )
      deck.deal();
    System.out.println(deck.cardsDealtList());
}
```

Comment: thank you it seems that was the problem I need to loop in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're overcomplicating. You only need to call `deal` more than once. You don't even need to store the dealt `Card` as variable. Your `Deck` already stores all cards dealt, you only need to call `cardsDealtList()`:

```
public class TestDeck
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Deck deck1 = new Deck();
        deck1.deal();
        deck1.deal();
        System.out.println(deck1.cardsDealtList());

    }
}
```

Comment: yes but its not keeping  all the cards in there its replacing them each time i deal again. Its a card game I'm going to deal many times until i don't have any more cards to deal

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping all the cards"? This will print 2 cards. If you deal once more, it will print 3. If you use a loop you can define how much times you want to deal before printing.

Answer (score -1):

```
public Card deal() {
    int suit = 0, faceValue = 0;

    suit = random.nextInt(3+1);
    faceValue = random.nextInt(13) + 1;

    Card randomResult = new Card(suit, faceValue);
    dealtCards += dealtCards + randomResult.toString();

    return randomResult;

}
```

By modifying this line **dealtCards += dealtCards + randomResult.toString();** have all the dealt cards because you are replacing the value of that String with it self plus the new card.

Comment: By using '+=' you are appending, not replacing.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what `+=` does?

Comment: += takes what the String was and add to it

Comment: thats what i wanna do i want to append